# How do custom fields work in paypal ipn?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

Hello I am trying to make some sort of script for the users of my game which will deliver the goods ingame to their account.

First I'm storing a variable like the
uniqueid

What I want to do is locate that variable in a MySQL table after purchase.i know theres the custom field in paypal but im just too stupid to understand how to use it. I just need a simple understanding of it and i can do the rest.

I've done 2 weeks of googling but im just a confused person when it comes to this.

Answer (score 1):

Set this on the submit payment or subscripe

```
 <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.$custom.'"/>
```

It should be avaiable as $_POST['custom'] on the ipn

Comment: value="'.$custom.'" would be the variable like uniqueid right?

Comment: yeah, you can put this unique id there and then retrieve it later